# how to get id of a textbox with the signup control

Tags: asp.net, textbox, registration

im using the signup control that is within visual studio and im trying to get the id of textbox within so i can insert it in the database but in the code behind it wont recognize the id of the text box.
here is my signup aspx:

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="mainSignUp" runat="server" 
    CreateUserButtonText="SignUp" FinishDestinationPageUrl="copyPastPage.aspx"
     ContinueDestinationPageUrl="~/copyPastPage.aspx"
     OnCreatedUser="redirect" LoginCreatedUser="true" 
    DuplicateEmailErrorMessage="e-mail already in use, enter a differnt email.">
    <CreateUserButtonStyle CssClass="signUpButton"  />
    <TextBoxStyle BorderStyle="None" Height="35px" 
        Width="200px" />
    <WizardSteps>
        <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server" >
            <ContentTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Page Name:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
                                CssClass="signUpTextBox" Height="39px" Width="197px"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." 
                                ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="mainSignUp">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
                                CssClass="signUpTextBox" Height="39px" TextMode="Password" Width="197px"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." 
                                ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="mainSignUp">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            <asp:Label ID="ConfirmPasswordLabel" runat="server" 
                                AssociatedControlID="ConfirmPassword">Confirm Password:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPassword" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" 
                                BorderWidth="1px" CssClass="signUpTextBox" Height="39px" TextMode="Password" 
                                Width="197px"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ConfirmPasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" 
                                ErrorMessage="Confirm Password is required." 
                                ToolTip="Confirm Password is required." ValidationGroup="mainSignUp">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Email">E-mail:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
                                CssClass="signUpTextBox" Height="39px" Width="197px"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EmailRequired" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="Email" ErrorMessage="E-mail is required." 
                                ToolTip="E-mail is required." ValidationGroup="mainSignUp">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="EmailTextBox">E-mail(again):</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="EmailTextBox" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
                                CssClass="signUpTextBox" Height="39px" Width="197px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            <asp:Label ID="QuestionLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Question">Security Question:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Question" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
                                CssClass="signUpTextBox" Height="39px" Width="197px"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="QuestionRequired" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="Question" ErrorMessage="Security question is required." 
                                ToolTip="Security question is required." ValidationGroup="mainSignUp">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            <asp:Label ID="AnswerLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Answer">Security Answer:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Answer" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
                                CssClass="signUpTextBox" Height="39px" Width="197px"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AnswerRequired" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="Answer" ErrorMessage="Security answer is required." 
                                ToolTip="Security answer is required." ValidationGroup="mainSignUp">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" colspan="2">
                            <asp:CompareValidator ID="PasswordCompare" runat="server" 
                                ControlToCompare="Password" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" 
                                Display="Dynamic" 
                                ErrorMessage="Password and Confirmation doesn't match." 
                                ValidationGroup="mainSignUp" CssClass="PasswordCompare" Width="300px" 
                                ></asp:CompareValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                            <asp:Literal ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
        <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1" runat="server" />
    </WizardSteps>
</asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

iam using asp.net 3.5
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the FindControl method to find a particular control. I just tested this based on your design:

```
((TextBox)CreateUserWizardStep1.Controls[0].FindControl("UserName")).Text
```

Comment: i get this error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: try this as I have just tested this one. ((TextBox)CreateUserWizardStep1.Controls[0].FindControl("UserName")).Text